# Solutions of Linear Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I did a graduate course in linear programming a couple of months ago and I am revising my old lecture notes and I would like to have a clear understanding to the following:

We all know from basic Algebra that there are three possibility of solutions for linear systems namely:

(i) infinitely many solution

(ii) unique solution

(iii) no solution

For any linear optimization problem, we either have infeasible, unbounded or solvable. How related is this to the three possibilities of solution for linear systems above?

Also, there's this statement/remark that keep puzzling me all the time: "A solvable standard form problem has an optimal basic feasible solution; it does not mean that all optimal solutions are basic feasible". I am struggling to appreciate this remark because how can an optimal solution not be a basic feasible?

Comment: Consider the optimal solutions to this tiny LP: minimize $0x$ subject to $x \ge 0$.

Comment: @RobPratt can you expand a lil bit for clearer view of your idea?

Comment: $x^* = 0$ is an optimal basic feasible solution, and $x^* = r$ is an optimal nonbasic feasible solution for all $r > 0$.